# Java Integer with String?

Tags: java, string, int

I was wondering if it's possible to make up a command, let's say we have a `Scanner`.

Here's example:

```
Scanner INPUT = new Scanner(System.in);
int IsPoints = 0;
String isValue = INPUT.nextLine();

if (isValue.equalsIgnoreCase("give"){
   isPoints += The int value you want here;
}
```

So my real question is, is it possible to increase the `int` value of points, via a String command?

> The output, if it worked, would be give X (Amount of points you want = x)

So if I did give `5000` I'd get `5000` points, is that possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: what! I could not get you in the last few lines. Please, What is it again ?

Comment: You're asking how to find part of a string, then parse it into an Integer. What have you tried? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: You are not talking about casting a String into integer? Are you?

Comment: I'm pretty much after a point system. But, the point equals whatever you want. So, let's say I have 0 points, and I want 5000. I'd do give 5000, which would grant me 5000 points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int points = 0;
String value = input.nextLine(); // give 500

String[] tokens = value.split(" ");

if (tokens[0].equalsIgnoreCase("give")) {
   points += Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
}

System.out.println(points); // 500
```

This would take `give XXX` as an expression and then add X to your counter.

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed, although is there a way to do it on the same line, instead of give, then points? Thanks

Comment: I see now what you wanted, see my Edit. This would take "give 500" as an expression and then add the 500 value to your counter.